# Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following query that is executed in a stored procedure but I'm getting the error described above.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ejemplo] 
    @periodo VARCHAR(2), 
    @ejercicio VARCHAR(20),  
    @sucursales VARCHAR(50), 
    @departamento VARCHAR(2)
AS
    DECLARE @consulta NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @consulta = 'select balanza.cuenta, Cuentas.Descripcion, sum(total_mensual) as "Gasto Total" from balanza 
inner join Cuentas on Cuentas.Cuenta = balanza.cuenta where ejercicio = '+@ejercicio+' and periodo in ('+@periodo+') and sucursal in ('+@sucursales+') and departamento in ('+@departamento+') 
group by balanza.cuenta, Cuentas.Descripcion order by balanza.cuenta'

    EXEC (@consulta)
```

Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample parameters that are causing the issue?

Comment: Please go and look up "SQL injection", your code is vulnerable.

Comment: If you are having an issue with your dynamic SQL, try PRINT @consulta to reveal any issues.

Comment: Check the variables for single quotes.

Comment: I just updated the question with the full stored procedure.

Comment: I guess one of the `IN` variables are empty and produce the error. Check their values as suggested

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti. The parameter was too small to receive the input data.

Comment: @VictorZazueta - Please take Johns advice and read up on SQL Injection. You should never use Dynamic SQL like this without first sanitising the input (EVEN for internal apps)

Comment: Why is this even dynamic? It doesn't need to be. And, like @DavidG said it's wide open to injection. You need to fix that, now.

Comment: It depends on the definitions of the tables, and on the parameters you are calling with.  I've managed to create tables and call the routine without error. Please provide complete executable code that demonstrates the error.

Comment: There are safe ways to parameterize `IN` in t-sql, such as table valued parameters, string splitting functions and multiple parameters. You *do not* want to go with dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables `@periodo, @sucursales and @departamento`. You seem to be trying to pass it into a `'IN'` syntax. When you print the dynamic query, you get

```
select 
    balanza.cuenta, Cuentas.Descripcion, sum(total_mensual) as "Gasto Total" 
from 
balanza 
inner join Cuentas on 
Cuentas.Cuenta = balanza.cuenta 
where ejercicio = @ejercicio 
    and periodo in (@periodo )  ---Check this variable
    and sucursal in (@sucursales)  ---Check this variable
    and departamento in (@departamento)   ---Check this variable
group by 
balanza.cuenta, 
Cuentas.Descripcion 
order by balanza.cuenta
```

I think you might need to change the logic in order to pass it to the `'IN'` clause